# Laravel - make directory not working when is called by a seeder

Tags: php, laravel, directory, mkdir

I'm trying to create icons for sites created in the past using laravel intervention, and this line is to make directories to save the icons for each site using this seeder

I'm trying to run a seeder, in the seeder I call a function from my controller, but when the function tries to make a directory it's stopping works.

this is a part of my seeder

```
$route = $this->templateController->resizeImage($logo, $placeName, $domain);
```

and when I do a debug with xdebug, this line of code call to the function correctly.

my controller:

```
public function resizeImage($logo, $placeName, $domain)
    {
        $img = \Image::make($logo)->resize(32, 32, function ($constraint) {
            $constraint->aspectRatio();
            $constraint->upsize();
        });

        $route = 'img' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $domain . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'favicon.png';
        if (File::exists($route)) {
            $img->save(public_path($route));
        } else {
            $newRoute = File::makeDirectory('img' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $domain);
            $img->save(public_path($route));
        }
        return $route;
    }
```

All works correctly, but when I debugging this line

```
$newRoute = File::makeDirectory('img' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $domain);
```

I get this error in the artisan console

> mkdir(): No such file or directory
>
> at
> D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem.php:581
> 577▕         if ($force) {
> 578▕             return @mkdir($path, $mode, $recursive);
> 579▕         }
> 580▕   ➜ 581▕         return mkdir($path, $mode, $recursive);
> 582▕     }
> 583▕
> 584▕     /**
> 585▕      * Move a directory.
>
> 1
> D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem.php:581
> mkdir("img\testing")
>
> 2
> D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php:261
> Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem::makeDirectory("img\testing")

Note: This function works correctly when I use this controller with a form

Comment: Why is there a `makefile` tag in this question?

Answer (score 0):

I solved replacing the line

```
$newRoute = File::makeDirectory('img' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $domain);
```

to this

```
$newRoute = File::makeDirectory(public_path(). DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'img' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $domain,0777,true);
```